# AngularJS ng-show does not work with new DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have some `div`s with `ng-show` directives which work fine when the page loads.

Now, under some conditions, new DOM elements (again `div`s) would appear on my page. They already have the `ng-show` directive in them but for some reason these expressions are not being evaluated. Is there any way to 'force' AngularJS to reeval all `ng-show` expressions?

Not a JS developer, managed to do a little demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/xasjeqe5/1/

**Edit:** link to demo was wrong. Also here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="good(1)">TEST1</div>
    <div ng-show="good(2)">TEST1</div>

    <input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="add"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.good = function(i) {
    return i>5;
};

$scope.add = function() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("I am invisible!");
    var att = document.createAttribute("ng-show");
    att.value = "good(4)";
    newDiv.setAttributeNode(att);
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv); 
};
}
```

---

**Edit2:** to avoid some of the confusion.

I am not really trying just to integrate AngularJS to be able to add new elements. The reason for my question and the demo is that I have some server-side rendering involved which returns prepared HTML data. This HTML data has to be "inserted" into the existing page (that is why all the manipulation is happening). The prepared HTML data on the other hand is a mixture of plain HTML and AngularJS directives.

Comment: There's no `ng-show` in your demo. Please also include the code in your post.

Comment: @m59: true, I just saw it, I was pointing to the fiddle I forked... it is updated now

Comment: DOM manipulation code doesn't belong in controllers....should be in directive. Also approach is all wrong. Should be using data model in controller that drives the view. You need an array of data objects and use `ng-repeat`. To add you push a new object into array. Would then get rid of all the code currently inside `$scope.add`

Comment: Angular is more about structuring your application around elements that have behaviours than adding new elements with behaviours at runtime. Adding behaviours in a controller is an anti-pattern, as is using `document.createElement` - you almost certainly want to move this to a) a directive and b) use `$document` instead of `document`. You may also need to `$compile` the created element.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating and attaching DOM nodes manually, outside of the Angular world. Angular does not know anything about them, so they will not behave as you are expecting.

Rather than thinking in terms of DOM elements, Angular encourages you to think in terms of binding against a data model.  Then Angular can handle most of the DOM manipulation for you.

Here is an example that shows adding elements to the screen and optionally hiding them with `ng-show`.  Notice that we are not creating DOM elements explicitly - instead we are adding items to an array and changing their properties.  Then, in our view we bind to this array using a repeater, allowing Angular to create the new `<div>` elements for us.  Each item also has one raw HTML property that we bind against using `ng-bind-html`.  We need to pass this through the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service to tell Angular to trust our HTML string.  This turns off Angular's built in XSS protection that would otherwise kick in and cause an error.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z4odkfne/1/

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.items.push({
            name: "New item", 
            show: true,
            html: $sce.trustAsHtml('<span style="color:red">some html</span>')
        })
    };

    $scope.hide = function(item) {
        item.show = false;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items"
         ng-show="item.show">
        {{item.name}} {{$index}}
        <span ng-bind-html="item.html"></span>
        <input type="button" ng-click="hide(item)" value="Hide me" />
    </div>

    <input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="add"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason I am thinking in terms of DOM elements is because I have some server-side rendering involved and on specific events I get the rendered HTML in my JS code. Then I have to insert the received HTML into the existing page and this is what I tried to show in the demo. So according to your post I should think of the received HTML pieces as of collection of managed model elements, correct?

Comment: @Anton if you want to render server side HTML on the client (for some reason), use a combination of this approach and `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: And there is no way you can change the server to pass you back raw JSON data, instead of pre-built HTML?  This would be the Angular way of doing it.

Comment: Well using JSON data and your approach would be really easy as I see from the fiddle but I am stuck with receiving pre-built HTML

Comment: @MikeChamberlain that looks really good. But I still have troubles when I insert some expressions in the html property - the expressions are being shown just _'as-is'_ and not evaluated. Is this where the `$compile` comes into play?

Comment: That would be one way of doing it, but it's quite advanced.  You are going to want to do this from a directive, not the controller.  See http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx for an example.

Comment: If your main goal is only to render server-generated HTML to the page, then I question if Angular is the best tool for the job.  Perhaps it would be more simple with jQuery or plain old javascript. Angular is explicitly designed for client-side rendering and any attempt to work against could end up overly complex and/or messy, especially from someone's who's new to JavaScript and Angular. Honestly, generating HTML containing Angular directives on the server, then rendering them on the client seems like a really Bad Idea, from both an architectural and an implementation point of view.

Comment: Reading the post you mentioned which is dealing with $compile and directives led me indeed to rethinking the whole stuff. Going so deep into advanced AngularJS features rings a bell and is a good sign for stopping and thinking it over. Thanks for the hints!!